# Same login/password pair is used for multiple threads sign in

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to simulate the scenario when multiple users(100) are logged in using login\password from my CSV file, where I have 10 different combinations of valid credentials. But the problem is that JMeter always takes the same login\password pair from my CSV file for all simulated users. The only way to solve it is to set Ramp-Up period of my Thread Group to be 0, but this seems to be not so plausible scenario, is it?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure `Sharing Mode` is set to `All Threads`.

Also, it looks like you're trying to have 100 Threads split up a set of 10 credentials, and there's not enough to go around. You will probably get 10 sets of threads all logging in with the same username/password. Try adding more usernames.

I'm not sure why a very small ramp up would fix this unless: if you don't have any think times, a user might go through your script quite quickly, then log in again with the same credentials. Even then, I'd expect it to get a new set, though.

SEE:
[CSV_Data_Set_Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config)